# Sum Value from a Text String

Tags: php

I have clients you enter bedrooms as 1 + 2 instead of entering the overall total which in this case would be 3. There is method in PHP that will allow me to take a simple string and generate the sum value?

```
$bedrooms = '1 + 2';
```

Comment: Why not cleanup the validation? So that clients DON'T enter 1+3? Might be the cleaner way to go, as you might open yourself up to something like 1m + 3child, etc;

Comment: What if I enter '2 & maybe a 3rd'? Require a number, have a comment/textfield for further instructions.

Comment: I have to leave it this way as 1 + 2 means one bedroom on main floor and two bedrooms on second floor and this how they like it displayed. Now I am getting into mirroring listings for my clients and the providers I am mirror to do not want it this way. I leave as is and try the answers below. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: display and input are not the same thing, get discrete usable input, then format the display any way you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$bedrooms = array_sum(explode("+", str_replace(" ", "", "1 + 2")));
```

Comment: Oh my you are more savoir. That worked out perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Look up [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) - That should do the trick.

But ensure that you have a good regular expression to ensure that the input will not do any harm

e.g. `^[1-9]+ *(+ *[1-9]+)*$'

Comment: @T - Knowing the vulnerabilities and still being able to use it safely isn't ;) +1 For the sanitation regex Ed!

Comment: Weird thing that eval in Perl makes code safer - it implements exceptions!

Answer (score 1):

parse that string by +
into array
add the values

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $bedrooms = 1 + 2;
    $pattern = '/([a-zA-Z \+\-])+/';
    $replacement = '+';
    echo array_sum(explode('+', preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $bedrooms)));
```

just to make sure some characters are in the input string